# Get all open disputes for an app

Tags: facebook

Is there a Graph API endpoint to get all open (local currency) disputes for an app?
Couldn't find it in the documentation. Been searching for a while now.
/[app id]/disputes yields the following error:
"Unknown path components: /disputes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disputes is a connection of payment not the app. I think you would have to get all the payments for a particular app

/appid/payments

then loop through the id for each payment and see if it is disputed

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/payment/

Alternatively, subscribe to realtime updates for payment

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

and store the disputes in your own DB